# how to record the input time on a textbox control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have been working on some assignment and was facing a problem...

**how to record the input time on a text-box control in asp.net**
that is the timer starts at the time when i start to input in the text-box and stops when i move to the next text-box or move to any other control.. ??

```
<table style="width: 685px">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="174px" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/registerwithus.jpg"
                    Width="605px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User&nbsp; Name
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter the correct Name" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Choose Password
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                    ErrorMessage="Choose Password" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Confirm Password
            </td>
            <td class="style6" colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Choose Password" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBox2"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Both the Password fields do not match"
                    ForeColor="#CC0000" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Email Id
            </td>
            <td class="style6" colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter your EmailId" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Id" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mob No
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Mobile No."
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9]{9}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You can start the timer 'OnFocus' Event and stop it 'OnBlure' Event

Comment: GotFocus, LostFocus & OnBlure events for TextBox are in Windows Control but not for WebControls ......so pzz sir can u suggest me any other  possible way...??

Answer (score 0):

You can start the timer on `focus` event and stop it on `blur` event.
Here is a sample

```
$(function(){
     $("#<%=TextBox.ClientID%>")
          .focus(function () {
               // Start Timer
          })
          .blur(function () {
               // Stop Timer
    });
)};
```